# Extract filename and its extension from a text

Tags: file, command-line, sed, grep

I have a text file that contain something like this:

```
Files /dir/AAA.mp3. Files /dir/BBB.mp3 Files /dir/CCC.mp3 Files /dir/{...}.mp3
```

I want to extract file name and its extension to have AAA.mp3, BBB.mp3, ,ccc.mp3 and {...}.mp3.
I tried to use grep in various ways but it returns whole line.
pleas help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -oP '(?<=/)([^/]*mp3)' textfile
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @JS. Perfectly did the job.

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` supports `-P` (Perl-like regular expressions) and `-o` (print only the matching part), you can try

```
grep -Po ''[^/]*?mp3'
```

Comment: oh Thanks @choroba. But it resturns  "/dir/AAA.mp3" instead of "AAA.mp3". Maybe there is no other way than using sed, but I'm a newbie and sed syntaxes are confusing for me.